# OffsetOutOfRangeException when reading from Kafka Store Changelog

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams app that's reading from a Store Changelog, that occasionally throws this error:

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetOutOfRangeException: Offsets out of range with no configured reset policy for partitions: {topic-partition=offset}
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseCompletedFetch(Fetcher.java:928)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1185)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1115)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StoreChangelogReader.restore(StoreChangelogReader.java:84)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.updateNewAndRestoringTasks(TaskManager.java:319)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:789)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:750)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:720)
```

I thought the consumer was supposed to default to `latest`. Even when I've tried configuring my Stream Properties using `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` to either `latest` or `earliest`, I still see this error. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configuring the consumer reset policy is only possible for reading from the actual input topics.

For changelog topics (ie, restore case), the reset policy is always set to `none` internally, because Kafka Streams needs to handle this case manually. The exception is caught and logged as a WARN level message. Afterwards, Kafka Streams does some  internal cleanup and a manual `#seekToBeginning()` to restart the restore process cleanly.

There is no reason to worry about this. However, a WARN message is logged to inform you about the event.